# Drupal (and Symfony ?) console, how go back to the previous command

Tags: shell, symfony, drupal-8, symfony-console

By example, when I generate a new module with Drupal Console, I must enter several data via the drupal concole prompt.

My question is, if I do i mistake, how can I cancel the current command and go back to the previous command ?

I mean :

[image]

Here, I said "no" to "Do you want to load services.." but I wanted say yes. Is there a way for cancel the current command and go back to the "Do you want to load services..." instead of cancel the prompt (ctrl +c) and do again all commands ?

Thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

I know you what you are feeling ;)

Sadly you will have to redo everything. However, don't forget that the commands accept an `[options]` parameter where you can already specify some parameters.